# Add ListView Row data to another ListView and save it? Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView with songs and a player. In my `ListView` I want to add a function to `button` to save `ListView` row and add it in different ListView in different Activity(Favorites Activity). How can I do this?

This is my code for Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] song_icon;
    boolean pausedSamePos = false;
    String[] song_name;
    String[] song_duration;
    String[] song_duration_sb;
    private final int mLcdWidth = 0;
    private final float mDensity = 0;
    public static MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    public static Boolean isPlaying = Boolean.valueOf(false);
    public static int pos = 55;
    Ids holder;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable updateTimeProgressBar;

    public Adapter(Context c, String[] song_titles, int song_Icons[],
            String[] song_durations) {
        super(c, R.layout.item, R.id.textview_song_duration,
                song_titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.song_icon = song_Icons;
        this.song_name = song_titles;
        this.song_duration = song_durations;
        this.song_duration_sb = song_durations;

    }

    final int[] songPos = { R.raw.song1, R.raw.song2, R.raw.song3,
            R.raw.song4, R.raw.song5, R.raw.song6, R.raw.song7,
            R.raw.song8, R.raw.song9, R.raw.song10,
            R.raw.song11, R.raw.song12, R.raw.song13,
            R.raw.song14, R.raw.song15, R.raw.song16,
            R.raw.song17, R.raw.song18, R.raw.song19,
            R.raw.song20, R.raw.song21, R.raw.song22,
            R.raw.song23, R.raw.song24, R.raw.song25,
            R.raw.song26, R.raw.song27, R.raw.song28,
            R.raw.song29, R.raw.song30, };

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        return getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public int getAdapterViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        holder = null;
        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
            holder = new Ids(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Ids) row.getTag();

        }

        if (Adapter.isPlaying && Adapter.pos == position) {

            if (pausedSamePos == true) {
                holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            holder.song_currenttime_sb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.song_duration.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.song_duration_sb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.song_currenttime_sb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.song_icon.setImageResource(song_icon[position]);
            holder.song_duration_sb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.song_duration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.pauseed_play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.playing_pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        holder.song_name.setText(song_name[position]);
        holder.song_duration.setText(song_duration[position]);

        holder.song_duration_sb.setText(song_duration_sb[position]);
        final Ids finalHolder = holder;


        holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "The favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }

        holder.clickRegister
                .setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        stopPlaying();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        finalHolder.song_currenttime_sb.setTag(position);
        holder.seekbar.setFocusable(true);
        holder.seekbar.setTag(position);
        holder.clickRegister.setTag(position);
        holder.song_icon.setTag(position);
        holder.song_name.setTag(position);
        holder.song_duration.setTag(position);
        holder.song_duration_sb.setTag(position);

        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                (int) (mLcdWidth - 10 * mDensity), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        holder.menu_options.measure(widthSpec, 0);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) holder.menu_options
                .getLayoutParams();
        params.bottomMargin = -holder.menu_options.getMeasuredHeight();
        holder.menu_options.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return row;
    }
```

What I want TLDR: To get song_name,song_duration,songPos on Clicked Row, and save it and then use that data to populat ListView in Favorites Activity.

If some more details are required I will be glad to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically the correct way is:

1) Create a `Song` model class and declare all required attributes inside this class

2) Extend the `BaseAdapter` and use an `ArrayList<Song>` as its data

Using this approach you will be able to easily retrieve a `Song` object from the clicked row and pass it anywhere you want. If you have no clue what I'm talking about then you are missing some basic knowledge about the `ListView` and its pointless to just throw code at you. There are tons of tutorials, check out [this one](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/) or [that one](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did as you said and changed my adapter. Those 2 tutorials were very helpful. But I still have problems retrieving row and saving it. I tried following some bad tutorials like this one [link](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-store-list-of-values-in-sharedpreferences/) but it didn't help. Do you perhaps know any tutorial for saving and retrieving row values?

Comment: @SlimC. what exactly is your problem? Assumed your `Adapter` uses an `ArrayList<Song>` you would get your row as following: `Song song = (Song) mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);` You can get the position using an `OnItemClickListener` or from the `getView()` method

Comment: The problem was solved, it took me a bit time but I did it. Thanks and respect!

Comment: @SlimC. glad I was able to help. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

there is so much ways to imp this , here is a way that i would use
save your data (song_name,song_duration,songPos) in an object in the shared preferences

and when you go to the fav activity read that shared preferences you saved

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "The favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
             //for example get the fav here and save it in object
        YoursongInfoObject yourSongInfoObject=new YoursongInfoObject();
        yourSongInfoObject.name=holder.song_name.getText();
        .
        .
        .
        .
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE,  Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        try {
        editor.putString("YourSongInfoID", ObjectSerializer.serialize(yourSongInfoObject));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
          editor.commit();
        }
```

and your fav activity

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (null == currentFavSong) {
        currentFavSong = new YourSongInfoObject();
    }

    //      load tasks from preference
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    try {
        currentFavSong = (YourSongInfoObject) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(prefs.getString("YourSongInfoObject", ObjectSerializer.serialize(new YourSongInfoObject())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```